# android dex unable to merge

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

running project is facing with this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

and this is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arnick.bazim"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.8"
        multiDexEnabled true //Add this
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "#onesingal_app_id",

                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'

    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

is there any special code I'm missing?
I should mention that this is an old project of mine which I have not worked on it for 4 months and now I am working on it again. 4 months ago everything was fine. 
Does anyone know what is the problem?thanks

Comment: Add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies. And confirm that your have extended the `Application` class and `MultiDex.install(this);` is inside the `attachBaseContext()` method. If you haven't done that, take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: You're compiling the libs directory twice

Comment: @th3pat3l `minSdkVersion 21`... So, that's not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I could compile your configuration at first attempt, but I saw a warning about the `com.google.android.gms` version used for some module.

For instance, running `gradle app:dependencies` I could notice this:

```
+--- com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5
|   +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:[10.2.1,11.3.0) -> 11.2.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.2.2
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1,11.3.0) -> 11.2.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.2.2 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.2.0) -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.2.0) -> 26.0.2 (*)
```

So for example `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:[10.2.1,11.3.0) -> 11.2.2` refers version 11.2.2

While firebase refers version 11.6.2

```
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-license:11.6.2
```

So since you already have a resolution strategy I would change it like this:

```
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.2'
        }
    }
    if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
        details.useVersion '11.6.2'
    }

}
```

My warning disappeared and I hope it can help you in your case.

**UPDATE**

I confirm that running the command

`gradle app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug`

As reported in your exception, I first had your same result with your configuration and then a successful build with the change I suggested.